# Trigger for checking a given value before INSERT or UPDATE on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have to create a trigger to update a database where there are products. Products have an expiration date and before inserting or updating a product I must check if the expirationDate is superior to the current timestamp. If it is I must do the insert/update regularly (this is what I have problems with). If not I just simply ignore it.

Here's the code that I have written.

```
CREATE FUNCTION product_expiration_date()
RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$

BEGIN
IF new.expirationDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN
    INSERT INTO Product VALUES (new).*; 
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER verify_expiration_date BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Product 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE product_expiration_date();
```

Comment: Aside: don't quote the language name. It's an identifier, not a value. Use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` without quotes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your trigger function should return `NEW` when the condition to check is satisfied and you want the INSERT/UPDATE to happen, otherwise `NULL` to skip the operation, or better, raise an exception with a specific error message.

It must not execute itself the INSERT it was called for, this will be done by the SQL engine with the values in `NEW`.

Code to skip the operation:

```
IF new.expirationDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN
  RETURN NEW;
ELSE 
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;
```

Or with an exception:

```
IF new.expirationDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN
  RETURN NEW;
ELSE 
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid expiration date';
END IF;
```

See [Overview of Trigger Behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html) in the doc for more.

Answer (score 19):

### CHECK constraint

The easiest way to achieve this goal is via the [`CHECK`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-the-single_table-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) constraint, which is an SQL standard feature.

```
ALTER TABLE Product
ADD CONSTRAINT verify_expiration_date_check
CHECK (expirationDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

### Trigger function

You could also use a [`BEFORE INSERT`](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-trigger-consistency-check/) or `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, but that's more suitable when the validation rule needs to inspect multiple tables, not just the current on that triggered the check.

Now, if you really want to use a trigger function, this is how it would look like in your case

First, you need to create the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION product_expiration_date()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.expirationDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Product [id:%] expired!',
    NEW.id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Notice that we are throwing an exception using `RAISE` if the `expirationDate` is greater than the current timestamp.

Now, you need to pass this trigger function to an INSERT and UPDATE trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER verify_expiration_date 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Product 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE product_expiration_date();
```

Although you could use a trigger function, it's much easier to use a `CHECK` constraint.